# HttpResponseData WriteStringAsync + HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, exception, azure-functions, blazor

I have a C# function that carries out some validation on the front end of Blazor WASM. I have noticed something weird that I can't understand but essentially if my Http Status code is set to a 2XX.. then my wait `response.WriteStringAsync(ex.Message);` shows on my Blazor front End

If I have my status code set as 4XX or 5XX it doesn't show my hard coded exception messages but a general response such as `net_status_code_error 404`

```
try {
    switch (name) {
      case "Invalid":
        throw new SpecialException("Validation exception.");

      case "Bad":
        throw new Exception("System exception.");
    }
    var url = $"{UrlRoot}/func?name={name}";

    var req2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url){};

    req2.Headers.Authorization =
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.Token);

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var resp2 = await httpClient.SendAsync(req2);

    var responseBody = await resp2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (!resp2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{resp2.StatusCode}: {responseBody}");
    }
 
}
catch (SpecialException Ex)
{
    logger.LogWarning(Ex, name);
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    await response.WriteStringAsync(Ex.Message);
    return response;
}
```

Now at the moment this just shows the Bad Request generic error but not my ex.Message on the front end? I don't understand why it works with 2XX but not other errors

Comment: I see a `catch` but no `try`... share more code!

Comment: @galdin Added some more code from my try statement; not sure if it affects my issue

Comment: Your `catch` only handles `SpecialException`s. Not the generic `Exception`. When `name` is `"Invalid"`, you see what you expect because you throw a `SpecialException` there. Do the same in the other places and you should see your custom exception message. In the future, try using Visual Studio's  (or VS Code's) debugger.. it makes it dead simple to find why a piece of code is not running like you'd expect. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Oh i do have the exact same thing for the Exception too except its a CreateResponse (InternalServerError) but it only shows what i want when its a 2XX status code

Comment: If your question is about `req.CreateResponse()`... show how `req` is setup.

Comment: my req is just `HttpRequestData req` which is used in .NET 5 Isolated Function Parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234454/discussion-between-galdin-and-godlypython).

Comment: If you show  your client side code that calls this API it would help